# Oracle sql stored procedure data parameter losing single quotes

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Please can someone help a very newbie Oracle person. I have created a stored procedure in Oracle to drop a date range partition. The code I used to create the procedure is:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEW_EVENT_DELETE(palterdate in VARCHAR2) AS
  2  begin
  3  execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE ROSUSER.EVENT DROP PARTITION FOR(TO_DATE(palterdate, ''DD-MON-YYYY'')) UPDATE INDEXES';
  4  end NEW_EVENT_DELETE;
  5  /
```

This compiles fine, but when I attempt to run the procedure using:

```
exec NEW_EVENT_DELETE('03-FEB-2014');
```

it comes back with:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14755: Invalid partition specification for FOR VALUES clause.
ORA-06512: at "ROSUSER.NEW_EVENT_DELETE", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

If I user the command:

```
ALTER TABLE ROSUSER.EVENT DROP PARTITION FOR(TO_DATE('03-FEB-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

then it works. It would appear to me that the set of single quotes around the input date are being lost, as it's the same error message that I get if I attempt to run the ALTER command without the quotes around the date.

Anyone idea what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try NEW_EVENT_DELETE("03-FEB-2014"); instead of single ' '

Comment: @Unlockedluca: Oracle doesn't use double quotes like that. Single quotes are correct.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with quoted quotes, I've always preferred this format:

```
execute immediate q'[ALTER TABLE ROSUSER.EVENT DROP PARTITION FOR(TO_DATE(']' || palterdate || q'[', 'DD-MON-YYYY')) UPDATE INDEXES]';
```

or even:

```
  lv_sql := q'[ALTER TABLE ROSUSER.EVENT DROP PARTITION FOR(TO_DATE('<palterdate>', 'DD-MON-YYYY')) UPDATE INDEXES]';
  lv_sql := REPLACE(lv_sql, '<palterdate>', palterdate);
  execute immediate lv_sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in palterdate correctly in your execute immediate. Change it to:

```
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE ROSUSER.EVENT DROP PARTITION FOR(TO_DATE('''||palterdate||''', ''DD-MON-YYYY'')) UPDATE INDEXES'
```

You'll need to think about about sql injection though, as this code could potentially be hijacked.

Comment: re: sql injection - that only matters depending on the source of the incoming date. If it's calculated in some scheduled batch routine, it's highly unlikely sql injection is an issue (ie no user input). But yeah, anytime you mess with dynamic sql, you have to give this some thought. ;) (hence, avoid dynamic sql if at all possible)

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, look at the USING option to EXECUTe IMMEDIATE

```
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE ROSUSER.EVENT DROP PARTITION FOR(TO_DATE(:palterdate, ''DD-MON-YYYY'')) UPDATE INDEXES' USING palterdate;
```

And, for the SQL-Injection worry, a quick length check on palterdate will likely solve most worries. Hard to embed an extra statement in 11 characters! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you put quotes like this ?

```
1 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEW_EVENT_DELETE(palterdate in VARCHAR2) AS 
2 begin 
3 execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE ROSUSER.EVENT DROP PARTITION FOR(TO_DATE('''||palterdate||''', ''DD-MON-YYYY'')) UPDATE INDEXES'; 
4 end NEW_EVENT_DELETE; 
5 /
```

Explanation : why 3 quotes ? one to escape the other and one last to concatenate

Edit : sorry i used '+' to concatenate because i thought it was on SQl server, you must use the '||' operator

Comment: Thanks, all. Used the '''||palterdate||''' and it worked superbly!! Thanks again